# Insert SharePoint 2010 list item type Multiple line text using C# and Client side object model

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model, csom

How do I insert a `Multiple Line Text` in a table column with `nvarchar(50)`

How do I insert a `Number` into a column with `int`

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://sp2010");
Web web = context.Web;
List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("EmployeeTasks");
context.Load(list);
context.ExecuteQuery();
Console.WriteLine(list.Title + "\n");
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = "<View/>";
ListItemCollection allitems = list.GetItems(query);
context.Load(allitems);
context.ExecuteQuery();

SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
DataSet EmpDataSet = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da;

cn.ConnectionString = "";
cn.Open();
da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from EmployeeTasks", cn);
SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
da.Fill(EmpDataSet, "EmployeeTasks");

DataTable table = EmpDataSet.Tables[0];

foreach (ListItem listitem in allitems)
{
  //  Console.WriteLine(listitem["desc"].ToString());
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
   // for people and groups 
    Console.WriteLine("ApprovalManager: {0}",((FieldUserValue)listitem.FieldValues["ApprovalManager"]).LookupValue);
   //for multiline text ? errors put 

    Console.WriteLine("Comments: {0}", listitem.FieldValues["Comments"]);
row["Comments"] = listitem["Comments"].ToString();// throws an error 
// For Numbers ?
row["EmployeeID"] = Convert.ToInt32(listitem["EmployeeID"]);
 table.Rows.Add(row);
            builder.GetInsertCommand();
        }
        da.Update(EmpDataSet, "EmployeeTasks");
```

Comment: What are the errors? If you use Console.WriteLine can you see values?

Comment: da.Update(EmpDataSet, "EmployeeTasks");  -- error  string or binary data would be truncated

Comment: That means your table can't hold more values. You should either truncated `Comments` field using `comments.SubString(0,249)` or increase `nvarchar(50)` to `nvarchar(max)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
foreach (ListItem listitem in allitems)
{
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();

    //Multi Line Text
    if(listitem["Comments"] != null)
        row["Comments"] = listitem["Comments"].ToString();

    //Number
    int tempId = 0;
    if(listitem["EmployeeID"] != null && int.TryParse(listitem["EmployeeID"].ToString(), out tempId))
        row["EmployeeID"] = tempId;
}
```